# Can't figure infinite loop case

Tags: c, loops, timeout, infinite-loop

I have a function `range()` that creates and returns an array based on two parameters, min and max. The array is filled with integers between min and max (min included max excluded).

I know from a test result that there is an infinite loop case (10s timeout), but I have not figured out where it is.

Function:

```
int     *range(int min, int max)
{
    int length;
    int i;
    int *range;

    length = max - min;
    if (length < 1)
    {
        range = 0;
        return (range);
    }
    range = (int*)malloc(sizeof(range) * length);
    i = 0;
    while (i < length)
    {
        range[i] = min + i;
        i++;
    }
    return (range);
}
```

Or maybe i'm missing something and something else is causing the timeout?

Comment: Isn't it better to use `range = NULL`, or `range = nullptr`, instead of  `range = 0`?

Comment: @EugeneSh. Consider `if (length < 1) return`.

Comment: `sizeof(range)` ==> `sizeof(*range)` and anyway, it's horrible to have a variable named the same as the function.

Comment: @scatter Ah, missed this line...

Comment: How do you know it is this particular function that is taking 10 seconds? If `max` can be `INT_MAX` and `min` can be `0`, then you could be allocating 8 GB or more to do this operation. If your machine can't handle the allocation, you may be swapping as you are filling the array.

Comment: Well, `range = (int*)malloc(sizeof(range) * length);` is not correct. `sizeof(range)` is a size of a pointer and not `int`. Not that it will lead to an infinite loop though.

Comment: Are you sure it's coming from this function?  Are you just manually killing it after 10s or is there something else in the program that's monitoring it?  What are the inputs that cause the failure?  It seems like we don't have the whole picture here.

Comment: @jxh `min` can be `INT_MIN` for even more fun :) Then `length` is going to be... what?

Comment: So `length` should be `size_t length`.

Comment: https://tio.run/##bVGxTsMwEN39Faey2E0LhTUFiZEBJgYkhKLgOMlJjoNqBypQvj34bFdpEDed37337tmW20bK6QKN1EOlYG9dhf1le8cWkMb3JaaxQ2c9NqFxQLU@lKZRnI4dmg2EpjwK9sNobPFbFQ60Mo1r8wARA@c2GuQsAJEHt2QBW3JMxBp4mu3hWgQsLqAKDl60y2dIueFggIeRiPjIzsldqXUvOQXsax5TCFinCGLemwTeXoA6ouMfg7N8FfVQl6hVtRInwRzjq/UT4OgTJ8//Yr/iG4VBA9npVYJPli1C/7nOyNhnjxU4ZV0RA3KRrOOH7Dbw8PRcPN6/XN2QYIof4/cQ8UzIRQ7j9As

Comment: It's just timing out on that platform, it seems. https://tio.run/##bVJBTsMwEDzXr1gVVbLbFFqOpCBx5FBOHJAAVcFx2pVcp2ocqKjy9uC1TZNW@BJndmZ3dmQ5XUvZXqGRus4VLCqbY3m9eWBnkMbPc0zjFm3lsBaNBTrjfWbWitPvFk0C/pIdBDsyKlf4o1YWtDJru0k9RAzsrqFByjwQeHBPLWBKHSOxAB5rC5gLj4UBdHwHJ5qlHaRsvTfAfUkEvGF98jbTupScDJYFDy4EjKMF0c2NAtdegDqg5bvaVnwY9FBkqFU@FE4w2O3dQsWpVNVSKpWr/N0M@@UlmjsYYQJLtyR9w0jCHDMJOboAkgsv3YbfGzcUOLowIuW/RN7wg/ZEA5O/wH2fycSZwYLjCOYzf8J2RzY4eaRh0Q6S9wb6EV6E2zD2VWIOVlV2FeLiIroJz2OWwNPzy2r5@HpzS4I2PBNnjYg9IRcpNO0v - This prints out i at every million iterations, and it's still incrementing when killed.

Comment: thanks for everyones input, seems it does just run for more than 10 normally

Answer (score 0):

```
int *range(int min, int max)
{
    int length;
    int i = 0;
    int *rnge_ptr;

    length = max - min;
    if (length < 1)
    {        
        return NULL;
    }

    range_ptr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * length);

    while (i < length)
    {
        range_ptr[i] = min + i;
        i++;
    }
    return range_ptr;
}
```